# Numbered align with bracket

Tags: align

I have the following code

```
\begin{align}
s'(t) &= -\beta s(t) i(t)\\
i'(t) &= \beta s(t) i(t) - \gamma i(t)\\
r'(t) &= \gamma i(t),
\end{align}
```

and I want to enclose this with a bracket like a case, but maintaining the numbered equations.

Comment: See the `empheq` package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple with `empheq`. Needless to load `amsmath`, as it loads `mathtools`, which loads `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}[left=\empheqlbrace]
    s'(t) &= -\beta s(t) i(t)\\
    i'(t) &= \beta s(t) i(t) - \gamma i(t)\\
    r'(t) &= \gamma i(t),
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]