# How to make a system of equations with a number after every line and a tall curly brace on the left

Tags: equations

So, i have this code:

```
\begin{align}
S(t+\Delta) &= S(t)-\beta S(t)I(t)\Delta + \phi R(t) \Delta \label{S}\\
I(t+\Delta) &= I(t) + \beta S(t)I(t) \Delta - \gamma I(t) \Delta \label{I}\\
R(t+\Delta) &= R(t) + \gamma I(t)\Delta - \phi R(t)\Delta \label{R} \end{align}
```

I want this with the numbering after every line (i already have that); but i want an '{' in front of the three lines. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/278758/156344):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq} % (already load amsmath)
\begin{document}
ABC
\begin{align}[left=\empheqlbrace]
S(t+\Delta) &= S(t)-\beta S(t)I(t)\Delta + \phi R(t) \Delta \label{S}\\
I(t+\Delta) &= I(t) + \beta S(t)I(t) \Delta - \gamma I(t) \Delta \label{I}\\
R(t+\Delta) &= R(t) + \gamma I(t)\Delta - \phi R(t)\Delta \label{R}
\end{align}
From equation \eqref{S}, \eqref{I} and \eqref{R}, we have blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The referenced question is already listed as a duplicate to [Separate labels in `cases`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31951).  So this question should probably also be marked a duplicate.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I _do_ think this question is a duplicate of the linked question, but not _Separate labels in `cases`_.